# Force CSS to square image in a responsive container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a responsive image grid background in my website.
All its working fine with perfectly square images but when one image is for example 1px height bigger, the grid breaks.

**Example OK:**

```
[H][H][H][H][H][H]  
[H][H][H][H][H][H]  
[H][H][H][H][H][H]
```

**Example FAIL**

```
[H][H][H][H][H][H]  
[H][H][H][A][H][H]  
            [H][H]  
[H][H][H][H][H][H]
```

I dont want to use mansory o other plugins, this is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="resp pull-left">  
<a href="#"><img class="img-responsive indexUser" src="image.jpg"></a>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.resp{
    width:10%;
    height:10%;
}
.resp img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Im using Bootstrap 3. Is it possible to do it?

**EDIT WITH MORE INFORMATION**

I want to put only square pictures in order, sorry, without grid. The image containers are floating. This is the screenshot with the problem:

[image: my website screenshot]

Is responsive and I need to use % in with to adjust perfectly fullscreen allways

Comment: Use images width is 100%.

Comment: Set the height fixed in the HTML

Comment: You can find a solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400232/force-bootstrap-responsive-image-to-be-square?answertab=votes#answer-23518465

Comment: Too late, but thanks! @DiogoBruni

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can try here that might answer your question.  Of course, without seeing your code it's very hard to advise in a more in-depth fashion.

- If you're using Boostratp, why not wrap each row of images in a `row-fluid` container and use [it's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?  This will at least ensure that you don't get the dirty float bug, although it also means that you'll get a little extra space underneath the child elements of that one taller one.
- Or, set the parent anchor's height and set `overflow: hidden`.  This will essentially cut off the bottom edge of the taller image, although you would have to work through your break points.

As a code example of point two above:

```
.resp a{
    display: block;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Bear in mind that images in Bootstrap have `max-width: 100%` set to them automatically so they will always flow to the width of the container if wide enough.

Comment: Hi man! I can't use the grid because I need sticky images and grid has padding or margin, nevermind, with your answer is the same. The problem its not solved...

Comment: You need to ensure that the anchor has 'display: block' set, and that the max-height is correct for use.  With those two things in-place, you will not find some images falling taller than others (they will all be restrained at whatever height you set in the CSS).

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to provide a height and maybe even set overflow:hidden. Please provide more markup if you want a better answer.

This is one linked image in a div, not a grid:

```
<div class="resp pull-left">  
    <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive indexUser" src="image.jpg"></a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<figure><img src="images/edu.jpg"></figure>

figure img {
width: 100%;
}
```