# Force bootstrap responsive image to be square

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Images are created in a loop with:

```
<div id="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="row">
        <?php
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
        ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <a href="/admin/product/"   class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    title<br>
                    10  x viewed
                </div>
                <img src="/assets/img/product/<?php echo $product['img'] ?>" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The images  are from diffrent sizes **some are higher then the width**, and **some are wider then the height**. how can i force all images to have the same with as the height while being responsive.
It is ok for them to have widh:100%, but i can not use height:auto, the ratio will stay then.
What should i do to make my images squared while they are responsive and i dont know the %.

[image: Example]

**Example, the green shirt is not as high as his width**

I want to do this without jquery so CSS only!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can do this :

1. wrap the image in a container with `padding-bottom:100%; overflow:hidden; position:relative`
2. position the image absolutely inside that container.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/p9L2q/)**

**Explanation :**

Padding top/bottom (like margin top/bottom)  is calculated according to the width of parent element.As the `.image` div has the same width as its parent, setting `padding-bottom:100%;` give it the same height as its width so it is square (its content needs to be absolutely positioned or floated so it doesn't change the parent's size).

*HTML:*

```
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
            title<br/>3 x bekeken
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.image{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:100%;
}
.image img{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: I also added these for smaller images: `min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I have to add some extra styles, here is my case: 
`.image img {width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; object-fit: cover; position: absolute;`

Answer (score 33):

Here is the best solution for every size of images
http://jsfiddle.net/oboshto/p9L2q/53/

HTML the same:

```
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
            title<br/>3 x bekeken
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

New CSS:

```
.image{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:100%;
}
.image img{
      position: absolute;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: This one actually works. The web-tiki example above does not work well for portrait image (it crops them instead of fitting them in the square).

Comment: Its prefect answer, Thanks so much.

Comment: This one worked perfectly when the image was almost square.  It cropped just as expected.

Comment: Almost perfect, but it should be `min-width` and `min-height`.

Comment: @Raptor not if you want to see the complete image. With `min-height` the image will be cropped

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap every image in a div and then set the div's overflow to hidden. As long as the div is square then you're image will appear cropped. The div can be responsive as well. [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped)

Comment: but some images are not as height as they are wide.

Comment: You could add a small bit of javascript/jquery to handle figuring out the orientation. For example `$(function(){ $('.img').each(function(){  if($(this).outerWidth(true) <= $(this).outerHeight(true) {//not as wide as tall} else { //not as tall as wide } }) })`

Answer (score 0):

This link works for me.[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=MpXYr)
Instead of using `<div><img/></div>`, `background-position; background-size; background-repeat` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

web-tiki answer almost worked for me, for bigger images I had to add this HTML and CSS to have them centered within the square:

```css
.image{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:100%;
}
.image img{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
<a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
        title<br/>3 x bekeken
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is, in my opinion, a solution in the Bootstrap spirit:

```
<div class="ratio ratio-1x1">
  <img class="img-fluid src="my_image.png" />
</div>
```

Tested on bootstrap 5.3, but ratio was supported this way in Bootstrap 5 already, and in a different mode in Bootstrap 4 as well.